Connection between Nilpotent Groups and Nilpotent Matrices
In Group Theory, we define a Nilpotent Group to be one that has a lower central series that terminates with the trivial subgroup. Intuitively, I think about this group where we can successfully mod out layers of un-commutativity.
In Linear Algebra, a Nilpotent matrix is a square matrix $N$ such that $N^k=0$ for some positive integer $k$. I think about these matrices as acting on vectors by shifting them into smaller and smaller subspaces and eventually $0$.
Whilst it seems to me that there is a connection between the subgroups in the central series and the increasingly smaller subspaces that $N$ acts on, I feel that my understanding is very vague and unclear.
Given that they share the same name, I assume that there is a deeper connection. I'd like to know what the connection between the two is, at both a mathematically rigorous and intuitive level.

I think one reason is that, the adjoint action of a nilpotent group is nilpotent, that is, the $n$-th iteration of the action is trivial. Here $n$ is exactly the nilpotency degree of the group.

It is worth mentioning that the adjoint action being nilpotent is not really equivalent to the group being nilpotent, but at least it justifies the name.

@Ja_1941 This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Please notice that comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, I suggest to post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.

@MartinBrandenburg I see. I will put them as an answer.

A very important nilpotent group is the Unitriangular matrix group $U_n(K)$. The matrices are of the form $A=I+N$, where $N$ is nilpotent. The group arises as the nilradical of the standard Borel subalgebra of $GL_n(K)$.
On the level of Lie algebras, the connection to nilpotent matrices here is even stronger. The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{u}_n(K)$ of $U_n(K)$ is a nilpotent subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)$ and consists of nilpotent matrices, namely of strictly upper-triangular matrices.

You may want to add that every finitely generated nilpotent group admitsva faithful matrix representation by unitriangular matrices.

I think one reason is that for nilpotent groups, the adjoint representation is nilpotent. Let $G$ be a nilpotent group of nilpotency degree $n$. The adjoint action is defined, for every $g\in G$, by $\rho_g(x)=g^{-1}x^{-1}gx$. By the definition of nilpotent groups, the $n$-th iteration of this action is trivial.
It is worth mentioning that the adjoint action being nilpotent is not equivalent to the group being nilpotent, but anyway this does justify the name.
